# How to click a list element outside the display in Android Espresso?

Tags: android, scrollto, android-espresso

I have a list view with id "listview" that shows 30 items with id "bground". I can easily click the first item with:

```
ViewInteraction item = onView(
    allOf(withId(R.id.bground),
        childAtPosition(withId(R.id.listview), 1),
        isDisplayed()));
item.perform(click());
```

But if I try to click the 5th element (just using index 5 in childAtPosition), I get RuntimeException, because the view's area is not displayed to the user.

Ok, I first have to scroll the element to the screen first. Any of my codings with

```
onView (...).perform(scrollTo())
```

is rejected because I have to use onData. And any of my codings with

```
onData (...).perform(scrollTo())
```

causes AmbiguousViewMatcherException.

Any idea how to use scrollTo or how else to click the lower elements?

Thanks and best regards
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

for clicking in a listView we are supposed to use the onData instead of onView although i have implemented the similar kind of behaviour inside recycyler view using

```
onView(withRecyclerView(RecycylerViewId).
                atPositionOnView(0, Viewtoclickinsiderecyclerview)).
                perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

In listview probably you will just need to replace the onView with onData

Anyway you can use following link to know how to implement using listview
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/

Comment: The linked description from google.githab.io does not match, because my view does not contain Map.class data, and the adapter is an ArrayAdapter, not a SimpleAdapter; I don´t find out how to adapt that description from Map class data to my data.

In the layout inspector I can see that the listview contains several LinearLayout frames, each frame consists of two AppCompatTextViews.

Maybe I could identify the desired view by identifying the text or by identifying via childAtPosition; but any construct that thing I tried failed.

Now how can I scroll in my case?